# get_terms for all custom taxonomies shows invalid taxonomy error

Tags: terms

Hope you are well,

I am using WP Version: ***4.8.1***
I am a new wordpress developer. Please read my issue below.

I am creating a plugin that adds employees (*Which is custom post type*) and then add them to department(s) (*Which is custom taxonomy*). But I can't get the terms of custom taxonomy. It shows an error "Invalid taxonomy".

Here are the files details.

1. See the file in this path.
   ***root_respository_dircotry/admin/ay-employees-class.php. Line#24*** here I have registered custom taxonomy with init hook
2. and priority of 5. And then see this file        ***root_respository_dircotry/public/ay-employees-public-class.php. Line#15 to 28***  here I am getting the terms with
       init hook again and priority of 10.

***Note: Please install the plugin and use the short code AY_DEPARTMENT_CAROUSEL to output the terms.***

Comment: Could you please share your code? Without it it's difficult to identify what is happening. It could be that you are using a plural when you need to use a singular (department vs. departments) or it could be that you need to use taxonomy ID instead of name.

Comment: Ohhh, Extremely sorry I forgot to add code. Here it is.

Comment: _**Please not that I am doing all this in classes**_.

**Register Taxonomy**.
`add_action('init', array( &$this, 'reg_departments_ct' ), 10);`.
`register_taxonomy ( 'department', 'ay_employees', $args );`.

**Get Taxonomy**.
`add_action('init', array( &$this, 'get_departments' ));
add_shortcode( 'AY_DEPARTMENT_CAROUSEL', array( &$this, 
'ay_departments_carousel' ) );
function ay_departments_carousel {return get_terms( 'ay_emp_departments' );`}

Comment: It's rather hard to read your code, but it looks like you are registering a taxonomy called `department` and then trying to `get_terms` `ay_emp_departments` - you need to change one or the other.